# How to replace `4-7` into `4,5,6,7` in Bash

Tags: bash, macos, eval, ram, brace-expansion

**Goal**

I have a long string `s` which represents series of numbers separated by commas and dashes (see below). When several numbers follow each other, the two extreme numbers are written and are separated by a dash. For example, the series `4,5,6,7` is written as `4-7`. My goal is to expand this string to have all numbers separated by comas (`4-7` should become `4,5,6,7`).

**What I did**

Here is an example of string

```
s="4092-4093,4095-4097,4104,4107,4111,4125-4127"
```

I wanted to first replace the patterns of the type `4-7` by `{4..7}` (using sed backreferening)

```
a="$(echo $s | sed 's/\([0-9]*\)-\([0-9]*\)/{\1..\2}/g')"
```

and then evaluate the string to expand the braces

```
b="$(eval echo $a)"
```

However, when I run this last command, the expansion is done "in a factorial way" (leading to an explosion of the RAM usage).

**Question**

How can I replace the patterns of the kind `4-7` into `4,5,6,7` in my string?

**Versions**

I am on `Mac OS X 10.11.3` and uses `Terminal 2.6.1 (361.1)`

Comment: Do you have `gawk`?

Comment: I did not, so I installed it. Now, I have `gawk`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer using GNU awk which should perform better with large inputs:

```
#!/usr/bin/env gawk -f
{
    while ( match($0, /([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/, arr) ) {
        s = arr[1]
        for (i=int(arr[1]) + 1; i<=int(arr[2]); i++) {
            s = s "," i
        }
        gsub(arr[1] "-" arr[2], s)
    }
    print
}
```

---

Alternately, in pure bash (for better performance with small amounts of data):

```
s="4092-4093,4095-4097,4104,4107,4111,4125-4127"
re='([0-9]*)-([0-9]*)'
while [[ $s =~ $re ]]; do
  eval_str="printf -v replacement '%s,' {${BASH_REMATCH[1]}..${BASH_REMATCH[2]}}"
  eval "$eval_str"
  replacement=${replacement%,}
  s=${s//${BASH_REMATCH[0]}/$replacement}
done
```

Comment: @Remi.b, ...working now. Could probably make it faster with awk, as bash's string-replacement functions scale poorly with length -- is performance acceptable as-is?

Comment: Yes, performance is acceptable. My string is 50 times the size but I only have to run the process once. I actually ended up finding (and using) a solution that is probably not faster than yours. I suppose that for the purpose of other users I might have better to wait for a cleaner answer (using `gawk` eventually). What do you think?

Comment: I'm working on such an answer, so if you don't mind waiting... :)

Comment: @Remi.b: Amended. And EdMorton was looking over my shoulder as I was writing this, so I have some confidence that it's not too hideous. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
s="4092-4093,4095-4097,4104,4107,4111,4125-4127"
a="$(echo $s | sed 's/\([0-9]*\)-\([0-9]*\)/{\1..\2}/g' | tr "," " ")"
b=""
for i in ${a[@]}
do
   add="$(eval echo $i)"
   b="${b} ${add}"
done    
echo $b
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue:

```
echo 4092-4093,4095-4097,4104,4107,4111,4125-4127 \
| perl -lane 's/-/../g;print join ",", eval'
```

In Perl, ranges are written with the `..` operator rather than dash. Running [eval](http://p3rl.org/eval) on it expands the string to the actual list.

Comment: Very similar, for Perl v5.14 or greater. It's still an eval, just inside the s///: `perl -lne 'print s/(\d+)-(\d+)/ join ",", $1..$2/ger`

Answer (score 0):

It's because your code doesn't do what you apparently think it does. Consider just `s="4092-4093,4095-4097"`.  After being run through `sed` this would result in `a={4092..4093},{4095..4097}`. which after being run through `eval` results in:

```
b=4092,4095 4092,4096 4092,4097 4093,4095 4093,4096 4093,4097
```

I'm guessing you were expecting something like this:

```
b=4092,4093,4095,4096,4096
```

If you haven't noticed the difference between the two, it's that actual result is the all the possible combinations of both brace expressions. Your actual case is has many more combinations, resulting in [combinatorial explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_explosion).

Comment: The last question was about why; the new question is about what to do about it.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I edited the question after posting it as I figured out the "why" by myself int he meantime.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The question as originally asked was why. New questions should be posted a new questions.

Comment: @RossRidge, ...that's the rule *when they have answers*. Your answer wasn't posted yet when the edit happened.